# Matlab -- Conversion to double from cell is not possible

Tags: matlab, 3d

Can someone tell me why I am receiving this error -- 
??? The following error occurred converting from cell to
double:
Error using ==> double
Conversion to double from cell is not possible.

Error in ==> test at 18
    CX(end+1,:) = temp(1);

Here is the code:

```
file = fopen('C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\testFile.txt'); % open text file

tline = fgetl(file); % read line by line and remove new line characters

%declare empty arrays
CX = [];
CY = [];
CZ = [];

while ischar(tline) % true if tline is a character array
    temp = textscan(fid,'%*s%f%f%f','Delimiter',',<>'); % loads the values from all rows with the specified format into the variable data

    CX(end+1,:) = temp(1);
    CY(end+1,:) = temp(2);
    CZ(end+1,:) = temp(3);

    tline = fgetl(file);
end

fclose(file); % close the file

plot3(CX, CY, CZ) % plot the data and label the axises
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
zlabel('z') 
grid on
axis square
```

Comment: If you break just before the error and type temp(1) in the command line, what type is ans? Is it a cell array or a double array. I'm assuming that CX is a double array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [cell2mat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cell2mat.html) to convert from a cell array (what `textscan` returns) to a numeric array, which you can use (like append to, in your case) with other numeric arrays.

I would also recommend using [vertcat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/vertcat.html) rather than the approach you've taken to concatenating:

```
CX = vertcat(CX, cell2mat(temp(1)));
```

Or, you could read all 3 values in to a row and concatentate into a N-by-3 matrix instead... lots of options.

Comment: CX(end+1,:) = cell2mat(temp(1)); -- like that?

Comment: cell2mat will convert all the cell fields to a matrix at once; you can concatentate all of them at the same time that way. See the edit and give it a try; or post a **short** example of what is being read in and what CX should look like at the end, otherwise it is a little unclear what the best approach is.

Answer (score 3):

Quick guess: does using curly braces help?

```
CX(end+1,:) = temp{1}
```

Comment: Using curly braces gave the error: Improper assignment with rectangular empty matrix.

Comment: maybe temp(1){:}, but I think cell2mat is the correct way to go as @tmpearce pointed out